# Suggestion command Discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, command

my code does not work. Everytime I try to fix it it does not work. This is what I have finished at and it says that the command has not been found. Anyone got a solution?

```
@bot.command()
async def suggest(self, ctx, *,suggestion):
    
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit = 1)
    channel = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.text_channels, name = 'suggestions')

    suggestEmbed = discord.Embed(colour = 0xFF0000)
    suggestEmbed.set_author(name=f'Suggested by {ctx.message.author}', icon_url = f'{ctx.author.avatar_url}')
    suggestEmbed.add_field(name = 'Suggestion', value = f'{suggestion}')

    message = await ctx.send(embed=suggestEmbed)

    await message.add_reaction('✅')
    await message.add_reaction('❌')
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, a better way to delete command usage is `await ctx.message.delete()`

Second, you should use [client.get_guild()](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=get_guild#discord.Client.get_guild) and [client.get_channels()](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=get_guild#discord.Client.get_channel) instead of `channel = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.text_channels, name = 'suggestions')`

Also, if you could include any errors, it would be helpful.